# Unique local and Global address

Tags: ipv6

I use a DHCPv6 server (Centos) to configure hosts with a global IPv6 address. For the 
internal communications I want to use Unique Local addresses (ULA). Can I configure 
2 DHCPv6 servers on the same link so that the host have both adresses(global and ula) ?

---

I only get a fd80:abcd::254 address on my Win7 laptop and not a 201:db8:1234:3::/64 address. Is there something what do wrong or I missed?

Here below are my router (fortigate) and my DHCPv6 server config

**fortygate_fw_van~ (ipv6) # show 
config ipv6
    set ip6-address 2001:db8:1234:3::1/64
        config ip6-extra-addr
            edit fd80:abcd::1/64
            next
        end
    set ip6-manage-flag enable
    set ip6-other-flag enable
        config ip6-prefix-list
            edit 2001:db8:1234:3::/64
            next
            edit fd80:abcd::/64
            next
        end
    set ip6-send-adv enable
end

---

.@ipv6-wms:/etc/dhcp>cat dhcpd6.conf
shared-network ipv6test {
        subnet6 fd80:abcd::/64 {
                range6 fd80:abcd::100 fd80:abcd::254;
                option dhcp6.name-servers 2001:db8:1234:3::2;
                option dhcp6.domain-search "ipv6.local";
        }
        subnet6 2001:db8:1234:3::/64 {
                range6 2001:db8:1234:3::100 2001:db8:1234:3::254;
                option dhcp6.name-servers 2001:db8:1234:3::2;
                option dhcp6.domain-search "ipv6.local";
        }
}

Answer (score 1):

You don't need two DHCPv6 servers, you need one server that gives out both addresses. And don't forget to include both prefixes in your Router Advertisements!